# Jquery loop through xml list and assign variables

Tags: jquery

I have the following script which works as expected , it retrieves an XML list and assigns some variables

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pgGeneral_login/validate.php",
    data: { user:user , pass:pass },
    dataType: "xml",
    success:loginval      });  

function loginval(data){
    console.log("Returned" )

    valid = $(data).find('valid').text();   
    name = $(data).find('name').text();     
    pass = $(data).find('pass').text();


    };
```

What I would like to do is instead of assigning a variable to each of the xml results (valid = $(data).find('valid').text() ) is loop through the list an assign the value to the tag name without writing a huge list of code , if it was php I would use something like

```
    foreach ($row as $k => $v)
            $$k = $v
```

any help please ?

Comment: You can loop it using `$.each(data, function(k, v){ ... })`

Comment: I recommend reading this [fantastic answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5117172/427992) if you need clarification about variable scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will directly update global variable list and is not recommended.

Here you go,

```
function loginval(data){
    console.log("Returned" )

    // valid = $(data).find('valid').text();   
    // name = $(data).find('name').text();     
    // pass = $(data).find('pass').text();

    $(data).children().each(function(){
        // Directly adding to the Global list
        window[this.tagName] = $(this).text();
    });

    console.log(valid);
    console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This works fine , it gives me all the variables I need to work with , but why do you not recommend it ?

Comment: @Mick Well, it is a variable we are talking about. Accessing it as a property of `window` is kinda odd, don't you think? Also, this always updates the global scope and will overwrite any global variables with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to ATOzTOA's code, this will also allow you to dynamically add variables to the global scope (i.e. for use outside of your AJAX functionality). It uses the [`eval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP) function  which is [generally avoided in most JS development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/427992):

```
// Array of fields you want to traverse
var array = ['text', 'name', 'pass'];

// This is the data object you get from your AJAX function
var vals = {
    text: 'Hello',
    name: 'John',
    pass: 'Password'
};

// Loop through and assign your vars
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var key = array[i];
    eval('var ' + key + ' = "' + vals[key] + '"');
}

console.log(text);
```

Thought it was an interesting question, so this answer is purely to offer an alternative (if hypothetical) solution - I'd err on the side of caution if using this for production purposes.

Comment: Well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: If you look at my first paragraph you'll see I linked to the exact same SO post :)

Answer (score 1):

Thought its not quite what you could achieve with php, but I think it somewhat does what you want:

```
function loginval(data){
    console.log("Returned" )

    $dataList={};

    $(data).children().each(function(){
        $dataList[this.tagName]=$(this).text();
    });

    console.log($dataList )
}
```